# Spring Boot: Integration test with HttpSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/principal")
    public void principalEndpoint(Principal user) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(authentication);
    }

}
```

and the corresponding integration test whcich uses `@WithMockUser` as described in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/index.html):

```java
/**
 * implementation according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/index.html
 */
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(value = "Dani", username = "TAATIDA3")
    public void testWithPrincipal() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/api/principal").principal(new PrincipalImpl()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

`PrincipalImpl` is a simple implementation of `Principal`:

```java
public class PrincipalImpl implements Principal {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MOCKUSER";
    }
}
```

I also have the following SpringBoot configuration to authorize requests under the `/api` path:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MyApiConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").not().anonymous();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the request dispatched by `mockMvc` in `MyControllerIT` fails because a HTTP Status 401 is returned (not authorized). It would work if I change the `HttpSecurity` configuration to this

```java
        http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
```

then the request succeeds (HTTP status 200), but no `Principal` is injected and the Authentication object from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is from an anonymous user:

```
null
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
```

If I change the paths in `MyApiConfig` e.g. to this:

```java
        http.antMatcher("/someOtherApi/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/someOtherApi/**").permitAll();
```

then the call from `MyControllerIT` succeeds and also a `Principal` is injected, which is what I want. However, in this case the actual api under `/api/**` is not secured anymore...

I'm quite new to the concepts of Spring Boot Security. Somehow I would have to override the `MyApiConfig` to configure `HttpSecurity` differently for tests (or use a separate configuration for test while at the same time excluding `MyApiConfig`). How do I do that, or what's the best way to make the HttpSecurity setup not interfere with MockMvc setup?

Comment: Remove `@ExtendWith`, `@ContextConfiguration` and `@ WebAppConfiguration`. Remove the `@BeforeEach` method. Add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and `@Autowired` to `MockMvc`. You are using a resource service so shouldn't you be passing a token?

Comment: removed the annotations and added `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to the class/`@Autowired` to MockMvc. However the Principal is still `null`. I am planning to pass a JWT, yes, but for the moment I would like to resolve this problem first since it's unrelated and blocking (I suppose injecting the JWT would also not work because of `HttpSecurity`